# Combine two dictionaries into observable collection - C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a simple class defined as below:

```
Class Data
{
public datetime DATES {get;set;}
public double ValueA {get;set;}
public double ValueB {get;set;}
}

 Dictionary<double, Data> DictA= new Dictionary<double, Data>();
 Dictionary<double, Data> DictB= new Dictionary<double, Data>();
```

Values in **DictA** look like this; **(Dates, ValueA)**

```
1/1/2001, 100
2/1/2001, 150
3/1/2001, 400
```

Values in **DictB** look like this; **(Dates,ValueB)**

```
2/1/2001, 200
3/1/2001, 400
4/1/2001, 300
5/1/2001, 150
```

I also have a `observable collection` as:

```
ObservableCollection<Data> curveResults = new ObservableCollection<Data>();  
 public ObservableCollection<Data> CurveResults
        {
            get { return curveResults; }
            set
            {
                curveResults = value;
                base.OnPropertyChanged("CurveResults");
            }
        }
```

I want to get the collection populated as

```
Dates, ValueA, ValueB
1/1/2001, 100, null
2/1/2001, 150, 200
3/1/2001, 400, 400
4/1/2001, null, 300
5/1/2001, null, 150
```

Comment: What exactly has your observable to do with this?

Comment: Oh I want to use it to plot the data. I will use the observable collection then.

Comment: You can give the constructor of `ObservableCollection` an `IEnumerable` which `Dictionary` implements. Almost every collection implements it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want null values for double properties, class **Data** should be like this:

```
    class Data
{
    public DateTime DATES { get; set; }
    public double? ValueA { get; set; }
    public double? ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
        Dictionary<double, Data> DictA = new Dictionary<double, Data>();
        Dictionary<double, Data> DictB = new Dictionary<double, Data>();

        DictA.Add(0, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), ValueA = 100 });
        DictA.Add(1, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 2, 1), ValueA = 150 });
        DictA.Add(2, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 3, 1), ValueA = 400 });

        DictB.Add(0, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 2, 1), ValueB = 200 });
        DictB.Add(1, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 3, 1), ValueB = 400 });
        DictB.Add(2, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 4, 1), ValueB = 300 });
        DictB.Add(3, new Data() { DATES = new DateTime(2001, 5, 1), ValueB = 150 });

        var tempDictA = DictA.Values.ToDictionary(x => x.DATES, x => x.ValueA);
        var tempDictB = DictB.Values.ToDictionary(x => x.DATES, x => x.ValueB);

        ObservableCollection<Data> result 
            = new ObservableCollection<Data>(tempDictB.Select(x => tempDictA.ContainsKey(x.Key) 
            ? new Data() { DATES = x.Key, ValueA = tempDictA[x.Key], ValueB = x.Value }
        : new Data() { DATES = x.Key, ValueA = null, ValueB = x.Value })
        .Concat(DictA.Where(x => !tempDictB.ContainsKey(x.Value.DATES))
        .Select(x => new Data() { DATES = x.Value.DATES, ValueA = x.Value.ValueA, ValueB = null }))
        .OrderBy(x => x.DATES));
```